# How to store Blank and Null values in separate columns in Delta lake table azure databricks?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am getting data from SQL server some columns contain BLANK values and other columns contains NULL values how to store NULL and BLANK values to the Delta lake table in Databricks?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and Expected output.